# Checkstyle, no JavaDoc for getter and setter only works for getters

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, setter, getter, checkstyle

I am using the Eclipse Checkstyleplugin (v5.5). I want JavaDoc comments on all public methods except getters and setters. I know there is the option "allowMissingPropertyJavadoc" which does exactly what I want. But in some cases it works and in some it does not.

**This works, no JavaDoc required on gettes and setters:**

```
public class Test {
    private String name;
    private int number;

    public Test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

}
```

**And this does not, JavaDoc required on setters:**

```
public class Test2 {

    private Test test;

    public Test2() {
        System.out.println("Test2");
        this.test = new Test();
        this.test.setName("thename");
        this.test.setNumber(1337);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.test.getName();
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return this.test.getNumber();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.test.setName(name);
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.test.setNumber(number);
    }

}
```

It seems as if setters without an assignment are not recognized as setters. Is how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it requires the body to be exactly "this.name = name;"

You can see the exactly line here:
http://checkstyle.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/checkstyle/checkstyle/file/a485366ec8c3/src/checkstyle/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/JavadocMethodCheck.java#l819

Dumb, I know.